# Python zlib not decodable when returned by an http response

Tags: python, http, http-headers, amazon-s3, zlib

I'm using Amazon S3 to serve static files. When the Content-Type is just 'text/css' and I haven't compressed the file, it is returned ok. If I try to zlib.compress() the contents that will be returned and change Content-Encoding to 'gzip', the browser cannot decode the result.  In Chrome, the error is

```
Error 330 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

in Safari,

```
“cannot decode raw data” (NSURLErrorDomain:-1015)
```

Is there something special to do with python's zlib to make sure the result can be returned and decompressed by the browser?

Comment: Here's how to do with with the zlib library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695152/in-python-how-do-i-decode-gzip-encoding

Answer (score 5):

I have this same problem.

If you send the header:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Safari/Chrome show that error.

But if you instead send:

```
Content-Encoding: deflate
```

Safari/Chrome decodes the input fine.

Answer (score 2):

[gzip](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1952.html) is not the same as [zlib](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt).

Answer (score 0):

It is decodable. The problem is that the sender is lying to the receiver -- not a good way of ensuring harmonious communication. Try calling it "zlib" instead of "gzip".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the module `zlib`, (`originalString = inputFile.read()` and then `compressedString = zlib.compress(originalString)`) I am now using the module `gzip`:

```
stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
compressor = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=stream, mode='w')
while True:  # until EOF
    chunk = inputFile.read(8192)
    if not chunk:  # EOF?
        compressor.close()
        return stream.getvalue()
    compressor.write(chunk)
```

The result then is compatible to `gzip`; I don't know if it fixes your webserver issue as well.