# Is it possible to loop through Amazon S3 bucket and count the number of lines in its file/key using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Is it possible to loop through the file/key in Amazon S3 bucket, read the contents and count the number of lines using Python?

For Example:

```
  1. My bucket: "my-bucket-name"
  2. File/Key : "test.txt"
```

I need to loop through the file "test.txt" and count the number of line in the raw file.

Sample Code:

```
for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets():
    if bucket.name == "my-bucket-name":
        for file in bucket.list():
            #need to count the number lines in each file and print to a log.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using `boto3` you can do the following:**

```
import boto3

# create the s3 resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# get the file object
obj = s3.Object('bucket_name', 'key')

# read the file contents in memory
file_contents = obj.get()["Body"].read()

# print the occurrences of the new line character to get the number of lines
print file_contents.count('\n')
```

If you want to do this for all objects in a bucket, you can use the following code snippet:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    file_contents = obj.get()["Body"].read()
    print file_contents.count('\n')
```

Here is the reference to boto3 documentation for more functionality: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object

**Update: (Using boto 2)**

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()  # establish connection
bucket = s3.get_bucket('bucket_name')  # get bucket

for key in bucket.list(prefix='key'):  # list objects at a given prefix
    file_contents = key.get_contents_as_string()  # get file contents
    print file_contents.count('\n')  # print the occurrences of the new line character to get the number of lines
```

Comment: Trouble is, I am not using a Boto 3.0. My version of Boto is 2.38.0. Hence cannot try the s3.Object methods.  

Another issue is my files are all in .gz format and its gets even worse when I try to use Key.open_read as a fd to gzip.GzipFile.

It errs as 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell' or 'seek'

I was wondering if ther is any work around.

Comment: @Renukadevi, I updated my post to add an example for boto2.
To decompress gzip data, you can probably use the zlib library, see example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2695575/4072706
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank a ton ., that was so simple., I am new to AWS and your solution helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Reading large files to memory sometimes is far from ideal. Instead you may find the following more of use:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucketname', Key=fileKey)


nlines = 0
for _ in obj['Body'].iter_lines(): nlines+=1

print (nlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is only a storage service. You must get the file in order to perform actions on it (e.g. reading number of files).

Answer (score 0):

You can loops through a bucket using [boto3 list_objects_v2](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2). Because list_objects_v2 only list maximum of 1000 keys (even you specify MaxKeys), you must whether `NextContinuationToken` exist in the response dictionary, then specify `ContinuationToken` to read next page.

I wrote the sample code in some answer but I can't recall.

Then you use get_object() to read the file, and use [simple line count code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

(Update)
If you need key in particular prefix name, then add the PREFIX filter.

Comment: Hi thanks, May be i dint phrase my question in proper. I want to iterate through specific files in S3 and count the number of rows in it.

Comment: @Renukadevi : Please clarify meaning of "specific" . Do you mean file with prefix?