# How can I decode compressed zlib data in python?

Tags: python, zlib

I have some data that I need to decode using zlib. After a bunch of google searching, I think python could do the trick.

I am a bit lost on how to make this happen; can anyone set me up on the path?

The data is just encoded text; I know that I need to import `zlib` in a python file, and decode using it, but I am lost where to start.

I have started with this:

```py
import zlib

f = "012301482103"
data = f
zlib.decompress((data))
print data
```

Comment: Your example likely won't work because your string `f` isn't encoded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695152/in-python-how-do-i-decode-gzip-encoding

Answer (score 5):

use `zlib.decompress`. It takes a `byte` object (`Python 3.x`), hence you need to read your file in binary mode first ( mode `'rb'`), and then pass it to `decompress()`:

```
import zlib

f = open('your_compressed_file', 'rb')
decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(f.read())
```

If you're using `Python 2.7`, reading the file with mode `'r'` should be sufficient, as in `2.7` it takes a string as input.

If the data isn't a file, simply do this:

```
data = '9C 2B C9 57 28 CD 73 CE 2F 4B 0D 52 48 2D 4B 2D AA 54 C8 49 2C'

# for Python 2.7
data = data if isinstance(data, str) else str(data,'utf-8')
zlib.decompress(data)

# for Python 3.x
data = data if isinstance(data, bytes) else data.encode('utf-8')
zlib.decompress(data)
```

[Link to the docs for Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zlib.html)

[Link to the docs for Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zlib.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this; but it is not a file I have. Should I just save it as a text file and put text.txt ?

Comment: in that case, simply pass your data to `decompress()` if it's a `string` - if it's a `bytes` object, you will have to convert according to your python version.

Comment: Hi thanks for update for python 3.6. So the text I have, do i replace the data in brackets with it? Can you post your full example with the data? Here it is:
9C 2B C9 57 28 CD 73 CE 2F 4B 0D 52 48 2D 4B 2D AA 54 C8 49 2C

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Had already tried with that, it gives me this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code", line 5, in <module>
    zlib.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Comment: that's an indication that your data isn't valid - it may be incomplete. This isn't an issue of the code, tho.

Comment: I don't think this is gzip data. I'm trying to decode it too: it's from the puzzle at the bottom of this page https://www.mi5.gov.uk/careers/cta