# Troubles with gzip API response (python)

Tags: python, xml, api, zip, octetstring

I'm trying to read a file that comes from a response to Anaplan´s API. The problem is that I don´t know how to read the response because when I execute the code:

```
    url = f'https://api.anaplan.com/2/0/workspaces/{workspace}/models/{model}/files/{fileId}/chunks/0'
    headers = {
        'Authorization':'AnaplanAuthToken '+ keys["tokenInfo"]["tokenValue"],
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    r.content
```

the output is something like this:

```
    b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00{fDS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00[Content_Types].xml\xb5S\xcbn\xc20\x10\xfc\x95\xc8\xd7*6\xf4PU\x15\x81C\x1f\xc7\x16\xa9\xf4\x03\\{\x93X\xf8%\xaf\xa1\xf0\xf7]\x078\x94R\x89\nq\xf2cfgfW\xf6d\xb6q\xb6ZCB\x13|\xc3\xc6|\xc4*\xf0*h\xe3\xbb\x86},^\xea{Va\x96^K\x1b<4l\x0b\xc8f\xd3\xc9b\x1b\x01+\xaa\xf5\xd8\xb0>\xe7\xf8 \x04\xaa\x1e\x9cD\x1e"xB\xda\x90\x9c\xcctL\x9d\x88R-e\x07\xe2v4\xba\x13*\xf8\x0c>\xd7\xb9h\xb0\xe9\xe4\tZ\xb9\xb2\xb9z\xdc\xdd\x17\xe9\x86\xc9\x18\xadQ2S,\xb1\xf6\xfaH\xb4\xde\x0b\xf2\x04v\xe0`o"\xde\x10\x81U\xcf\x1bR\xd9\xb5C(2q\x86\xc3qa9S\xdd\x1b\r&\x19\r\xff\x8a\x16\xda\xd6(\xd0A\xad\x1c\x95p(\xaa\x1at\x1d\x13\x11S6\xb0\xcf9\x97)\xbfJG\x82\x82\xc8sBQ\x904\xbf\xc4\xfb0\x16\x15\x12\x9ceX\x88\x179\x1eu\x8b1\x81\xd4\xd8\x03dg9\xf62\x81~\xcf\x89^\xd3\xef\x10\x1b+~\x10\xae\x98#o\xed\x89)\x94\x00\x03r\xcd\t\xd0\xca\x9d4\xfe\x94\xfbWH\xcb\xcf\x10\x96\xd7\xf3/\x0e\xc3\xfe/\xfb\x01D1,\xe3C\x0e1|\xef\xe97PK\x07\x08\x91,(\xbc;\x01\x00\x00\x1d\x04\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00{fDS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00_rels/.rels\xad\x92\xc1J\x031\x10\x86_%\xcc\xbd\x9bm\x05\x11i\xda\x8b\x08\xbd\x89\xd4\x07\x18\x93\xd9\xdd\xb0\x9bLHF\xdd\xbe\xbd\xc1\x8b\xb6lA\xc1\xe303\xdf\xff1\xc9v?\x87I\xbdS.\x9e\xa3\x81u\xd3\x82\xa2h\xd9\xf9\xd8\x1bx9>\xae\xee@\x15\xc1\xe8p\xe2H\x06NT`\xbf\xdb>\xd3\x84RW\xca\xe0SQ\x95\x11\x8b\x81A$\xddk]\xec@\x01K\xc3\x89b\xedt\x9c\x03J-s\xaf\x13\xda\x11{\xd2\x9b\xb6\xbd\xd5\xf9\'\x03\xce\x99\xea\xe0\x0c\xe4\x83[\x83:b\xeeI\x0c\xcc\x93\xfe\xe0<\xbe2\x8fM\xc5\xd6\xc6)\xd1oB\xb9\xeb\xbc\xa5\x07\xb6o\x81\xa2,d_L\x80^v\xd9|\xbb8\xb6O\x99\xeb&\xa6\xf4\xdf24\x0bEGn\x95j\x02e\xf1\xf5\xe2W\x8cn\x16\x8c,g\xfa\x9b\xd2\xf5G\xd1\x81\x04\x1d\n~Q/\x84\xf4\xd9\x1f\xd8}\x02PK\x07\x08n2\x08K\xe5\x00\x00\x00J\x02\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00{fDS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00docProps/app.xmlM\x8e\xc1\n\xc20\x10D\xef~E\xc8\xbd\xdd\xeaAD\xd2\x94\x82\x08\x9e\xecA? \xa4\xdb6\xd0lB\xb2J?\xdf\x9c\xd4\xe3\xcc0\x8f\xa7\xba\xcd\xaf\xe2\x8d)\xbb@\xad\xdc\xd7\x8d\x14H6\x8c\x8e\xe6V>\x1f\xd7\xea$;\xbdSC\n\x11\x13;\xcc\xa2\x1c(\xb7ra\x8eg\x80l\x17\xf4&\xd7e\xa6\xb2L!y\xc3%\xa6\x19\xc249\x8b\x97`_\x1e\x89\xe1\xd04G\xc0\x8d\x91F\x1c\xab\xf8\x05J\xad\xfa\x18Wg\r\x17\x07\xddGS\x90b\xb8\xdf\x14\xfc\xf7\n~\x0e\xfa\x03PK\x07\x08\xe1|w\xd8\x91\x00\x00\x00\xb7\x00\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00{fDS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00docProps/core.xmlm\x90]K\xc30\x14\x86\xffJ\xc8}\x9b\xa4\x9b\xa2\xa1\xed\x10e (\x0e\xacL\xbc\x0b\xc9\xb1-6\x1f$\xd1n\xff\xde\xb4\xce\n\xea]\x92\xf79\x0f\'o\xb99\xe8\x01}\x80\x0f\xbd5\x15f9\xc5\x08\x8c\xb4\xaa7m\x85\x9f\x9amv\x81Q\x88\xc2(1X\x03\x15>B\xc0\x9b\xba\x94\x8eK\xeba\xe7\xad\x03\x1f{\x08(yL\xe0\xd2U\xb8\x8b\xd1qB\x82\xec@\x8b\x90\'\xc2\xa4\xf0\xd5z-b\xba\xfa\x968!\xdfD\x0b\xa4\xa0\xf4\x9ch\x88B\x89(\xc8$\xcc\xdcb\xc4\'\xa5\x92\x8b\xd2\xbd\xfba\x16(I`\x00\r&\x06\xc2rF~\xd8\x08^\x87\x7f\x07\xe6d!\x0f\xa1_\xa8q\x1c\xf3q5si#F\x9e\xef\xef\x1e\xe7\xe5\xb3\xdeL\x7f\x97\x80\xeb\xf2\xa4\xe6\xd2\x83\x88\xa0P\x12\xf0xt\xa9\x92\xefd\xbf\xba\xbei\xb6\xb8.h\xc12F3\xbanX\xc1\xcf\x18__\xbe\x94\xe4\xd7\xfc$\xfc:[__\xa5B:@\xbb\x87\xdb\x89[\x9eK\xf2\xa7\xe6\xfa\x13PK\x07\x08B/\xa4?\x06\x01\x00\x00\xb1\x01\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00{fDS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00xl/sharedStrings.xml=\x8cA\x0e\xc2
```

I was reading a lot about that but nothing seems to work. Can someone give me a hand? Thanks

Note:

here are the response headers if it helps

```
    {'Date': 'Mon, 04 Oct 2021 12:52:17 GMT', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions [Stackoverflow 2695152](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695152/in-python-how-do-i-decode-gzip-encoding)?

Comment: @marcelh I got this error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

Answer (score 1):

That is a zip file, not a gzip file. Use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module to extract the contents.